# Moving a sprite to another sprite in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

I am new to pygame and trying to develop an 8-Bit Shooter. What I want is when the user presses space, a bullet will fire and go until it hits a mob or the edge of the window. Here is the bullet class:

```
class BULLET:
    def __init__(self, location):
        self.pos = [0,0]
        self.image = NOBULLET
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.direction = 0
    def move(self):
        if self.rect.right >= screen.get_rect().right:
            self.rect.right = self.rect.right - 10
        if self.rect.left <= screen.get_rect().left:
            self.rect.right = self.rect.right + 10
        if self.rect.top <= screen.get_rect().top:
            self.rect.top = self.rect.top + 10
        if self.rect.bottom >= screen.get_rect().bottom:
                self.rect.bottom = self.rect.bottom - 10
    def update(self):
        while True:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                    if (event.key == K_SPACE and Gun.image == NOGUN):
                        self.pos == Player.pos()
                        self.direction == Player.direction
```

What I want is for the bullet to go to the Player when Space is pressed, and move in the direction the player is facing until it hits a mob or the edge of the window.

[edit]
This is the main shooting loop:

```
if AMMO > 0:
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and Gun.image == NOGUN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE and Gun.image == NOGUN:
            Bullet.direction = Player.direction
            Bullet.pos == Player.pos
            shot.play()
            print "BANG"
            AMMO = AMMO - 1
            time.sleep(0.09)
            Bullet.image == NOBULLET
```

Answer (score 0):

put a location and direction as parameters in your `__init__` I see that you already have a location.  Now you need to store those from the constructor to the class

where you have `self.pos = [0,0]` you need to instead set that = to the location passed in as an argument

do the same thing with direction by using `self.direction = orientation`

[edit]
Here i'll go into more detail for you, this is your init method:

```
def __init__(self, location):
    self.pos = [0,0]
    self.image = NOBULLET
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.direction = 0
```

You need to add an argument to it, right now it has two, one is self, one is location, you also need direction, it should end up looking like this `def __init__(self, location, orientation):`
Now when you create the bullet you will have to pass it the position of the player (x,y) and the direction he is facing (probably 0,1,2,3 for N,E,S,W)

Then you need to store those arguments by doing `self.variable = argument` for both location and orientation

Comment: @user2493744 I just added some more info for you

Comment: When I do what you say, the postion is still 0,0 and I didn't type in those cordinantes

Comment: I dont exactly know your code but lets assume you passed a list in for location  you would then write `self.pos = location`

Comment: @user2493744 you'd also have to write self.direction = orientation if you had that as a third argument

Comment: I did both of what you said, now how do I get the position of the bullet to go to the postion of the player when ever i press SPACE

Comment: @user2493744 Well do you have an eventhandler that gets called when you press  space?

Comment: Yes I do. But how to I set the postion of the the bullet to the player when ever i press space, it just stays in the same place

Comment: @user2493744 in that method, create a new instance of a bullet and pass it the 2 arguments you need, player location and player orientation, I can't see that code so I can't give you specific examples

Comment: I have thrown in the shooting loop

Comment: ok instead of saying `Bullet.something = blah`  You need to create a new one on the spot by saying `myBullet = Bullet(Parker.pos, Parker.direction)` that is called creating an object using a constructor

Comment: Ok, but when I create this, and run it, how do i set the position to be where the player is each time space is pressed

Comment: it should do that automatically

Comment: It doesn't move to the position each time

Comment: @user2493744 i need more information, what happens when you hit space, what do you want to happen, be specific